# Convolution using FFT gives a bad result

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to convolve an image using FFT. I use openCV so images are in Mat containers. I convert color image to gray image, then add a second channel for imaginary numbers that is all zero. Then I take this 2-channel Mat and convolve it with Prewitt's kernel. I get a result very different from the result I get when I use normal convolution algorithm. Left image is the output I get using FFT and right image is the output of normal convolution.

[image] [image: enter descripsion hier]

Below is the pseudo algorithm of how I do the operation;

```
Convert image Mat and kernel Mat to complex Mats by adding second channel (Result Mat type is CV_32FC2)
Assign all Mat elements to complex vectors
Zero pad the vectors to the same next power of 2
FFT the vectors
Signal multiply both vectors elementwise and assign result to result vector
Inverse FFT the result vector
Convert result vector to Mat
```

I think FFT algorithm is not the problem because when I take an image, FFT it, then inverse FFT it, I get the original image just fine. But I could be wrong. So [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#C.2B.2B) is the FFT algorithm. Notice how there are two of them. I use the second one. I also tried other FFT algorithms and they all output the same. FFT'ing and IFFT'ing same image only skips the signal multiplication step above. So I think that's where the problem is. Here is the code of the operation;

```
std::vector<cf> signalMultiplication(std::vector<cf> lh, std::vector<cf> rh) {
    std::vector<cf> imVec = lh, kerVec = rh, resultVec;

    resultVec.resize(imVec.size());

    std::transform(imVec.begin(), imVec.end(), kerVec.begin(), resultVec.begin(), std::multiplies<cf>());

    return resultVec;
}
```

I tried multiplying them using for loop but result was the same. I don't know the problem and I can't type the whole code here since it is too long, so tell me where you think the problem is and I'll give the code of that part.

@Paul below is the main body of the code;

```
cv::Mat convolution2D(cv::Mat image, cv::Mat kernel) {
cv::Mat imMat, kerMat; 

imMat = convertToComplexMat(image);
kerMat = convertToComplexMat(kernel);

std::vector<cf> imVec, kerVec, resultVec;

imVec = matElementsToVector<cf>(imMat);
kerVec = matElementsToVector<cf>(kerMat);

float power = log2f(imVec.size());
if (abs(power - (int)power) == 0)
    power++;
else
    power = ceil(power);

zeroPadding(imVec, power);
zeroPadding(kerVec, power);

//FFT code I linked takes valarray as argument so I convert vectors to valarray and back
std::valarray<cf> imCArr(imVec.data(), imVec.size());
std::valarray<cf> kerCArr(kerVec.data(), kerVec.size());

fftRosetta(imCArr);
fftRosetta(kerCArr);

imVec.assign(std::begin(imCArr), std::end(imCArr));
kerVec.assign(std::begin(kerCArr), std::end(kerCArr));

resultVec = signalMultiplication(imVec, kerVec);    
std::valarray<cf> resCArr(resultVec.data(), resultVec.size());

ifftRosetta(resCArr);
resultVec.assign(std::begin(resCArr), std::end(resCArr));

cv::Mat resultMat;
resultMat = vectorToMatElementsRowMajor(resultVec, imMat.rows, imMat.cols, imMat.type());

std::vector<cv::Mat> matVec;
cv::split(resultMat, matVec);

return matVec[0]; }
```

These are the custom functions;

convertToComplexMat, matElementsToVector, zeroPadding, fftRosetta, ifftRosetta, signalMultiplication, vectorToMatElementsRowMajor

signalMultiplication is posted, fftRosetta and ifftRosetta are linked so here, the rest of the functions;

```
using cf = std::complex<float>;

cv::Mat convertToComplexMat(cv::Mat imageMat) {
    cv::Mat matOper;
    if (imageMat.channels() == 3)
        cv::cvtColor(imageMat, matOper, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    else
        matOper = imageMat.clone();
    matOper.convertTo(matOper, CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat compChannel = cv::Mat::zeros(matOper.rows, matOper.cols, CV_32FC1);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    channels.push_back(matOper);
    channels.push_back(compChannel);
    cv::merge(channels, matOper);

    return matOper;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> matElementsToVector(cv::Mat operand) {
    std::vector<T> vecOper;
    int cn = operand.channels();
    int lele = operand.total();
    for (int i = 0; i < operand.total(); i++) {
        if (cn == 1)
            vecOper.push_back(operand.at<cv::Vec<T, 1>>(i)[0]);
        else if (cn == 2) {
            if (typeid(T) == typeid(cf)) {
                T xd = operand.at<T>(i);
                vecOper.push_back(xd);
            }
            else
                for (int k = 0; k < cn; k++)
                    vecOper.push_back(operand.at<cv::Vec<T, 2>>(i)[k]);
        }
        else if (cn == 3)
            for (int k = 0; k < cn; k++)
                vecOper.push_back(operand.at<cv::Vec<T,3>>(i)[k]);
    }
    return vecOper;
}

void zeroPadding(std::vector<cf>& a, int power) {
    int p, ioper;

    if (power == -1)
        p = ceil(log2f(a.size()));
    else
        p = power;

    ioper = pow(2, p);
    int size = a.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < ioper - size; i++) {
        a.push_back(0);
    }
}

template <typename T>
cv::Mat vectorToMatElementsRowMajor(std::vector<T> operand, int mrows, int mcols, int mtype) {
    cv::Mat matoper(mrows, mcols, mtype);
    for (int j = 0; j < matoper.total(); j++) {
        matoper.at<T>(j) = operand[j];
    }
    return matoper;
}
```

@Cris I tried it again with openCV DFT like you said, following the directions [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/tutorial_discrete_fourier_transform.html). I applied DFT to image and kernel, then element-wise multiplied them, then applied IDFT. But result is something very different now. I can see resemblance of original image in there, but there are multiple shadows of it in different angles. I think the problem is how I do signal multiplication, but I can't find any answers on how to multiply 2D signals. Here is the code, output image is below it;

```
cv::Mat convolution2DopenCV(cv::Mat image, cv::Mat kernel) {
    cv::Mat paddedImage, paddedKernel, imgOper, kerOper;
    if (image.channels() == 3)
        cv::cvtColor(image, imgOper, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    else
        imgOper = image.clone();

    kerOper = kernel;

    int m = cv::getOptimalDFTSize(imgOper.rows);
    int n = cv::getOptimalDFTSize(imgOper.cols);

    cv::copyMakeBorder(imgOper, paddedImage, 0, m - imgOper.rows, 0, n - imgOper.cols, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));
    cv::copyMakeBorder(kerOper, paddedKernel, 0, m - kerOper.rows, 0, n - kerOper.cols, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));

    cv::Mat planesImage[] = { cv::Mat_<float>(paddedImage), cv::Mat::zeros(paddedImage.size(), CV_32F) };
    cv::Mat cmpImgMat;
    cv::merge(planesImage, 2, cmpImgMat);
    cv::dft(cmpImgMat, cmpImgMat);

    cv::Mat planesKernel[] = { cv::Mat_<float>(paddedKernel), cv::Mat::zeros(paddedKernel.size(), CV_32F) };
    cv::Mat cmpKerMat;
    cv::merge(planesKernel, 2, cmpKerMat);
    cv::dft(cmpKerMat, cmpKerMat);

    cv::Mat resultMat = cmpImgMat.mul(cmpKerMat);

    cv::Mat planes[2];
    cv::idft(resultMat, resultMat);
    cv::split(resultMat, planes);
    cv::normalize(planes[0], planes[0], 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
    return planes[0];
}
```

[image]

That's everything, if there is something I'm missing, let me know.

Comment: A resize of a vector, a call to `std::transform`, and a return.  I highly doubt anyone can get any information from 3 or 4 lines of C++ code.  It's like saying something is wrong with your car, and then giving us a picture of the steering wheel to figure out what's wrong.  Better to post, as best you can, a [mcve].

Comment: Neither of those two images looks like it was convolved with a Prewitt kernel, so you have multiple different problems here. It also sounds like you are using a 1D FFT, not a 2D one, so you’ll never get a correct 2D convolution.

Comment: I highly recommend that you use an image processing library. It’ll give you all the experience of many people before you. Reinventing the wheel is a bad idea. If you’re just trying to get hands-on experience with new concepts, there are better ways of doing so than by fudging with std::vector. Use a true image type, from a well-tested and designed image processing library, and you’ll avoid all the issues that have nothing to do with the convolution you want to learn about.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added everything, let me know if there is anything I'm missing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm trying new concepts yes, I thought for a 1D signal std::vector would be just fine. You are right though, this should count as 1D FFT. Can you get me started on 2D FFT? Any sources I should check? And what container would be better for signals?

Comment: If you’re using OpenCV, why not use OpenCV’s FFT? Then at least you get a proper 2D FFT. It looks to me that you’re unraveling your image to a long 1D array, then applying the 1D FFT to that. That is not the same as a 2D FFT. A 2D FFT applies the 1D FFT to each row, and then on that result, to each column.

Comment: Prewitt is a derivative operator. The output has positive and negative values. Maybe it’s the way you display it, maybe you’re casting to an unsigned type. Either way you’re not seeing the correct output. To display a signed image, move the 0 to the middle gray, for example by adding 0.5 (if floating-point) or 127 (if converting to uint8).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did it OpenCV FFT like you said, see the edit. I also tried the Prewitt edge detection the MATLAB has and yes like you said, they are very different. But I think MATLAB applies double threshold, hysteresis and whatsoever. The only operation I did on image posted is convolution with Prewitt kernels. Nothing else. Could that be what you mean when it is different?

Comment: `cmpImgMat.mul(cmpKerMat)` doesn't do a proper multiplication. It multiplies element-wise, (real*real, imag*imag). Use [`mulSpectrums`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mulspectrums) instead. Because of this, your result has a symmetry it shouldn't (you can rotate by 180 degrees and see the same image). However, the result is closer to what you're after, with both positive and negative values. Note that you can pass real-valued images into `dft`, and then `idft` will yield a real-valued image as well.

Comment: By the way, MATLAB's `edge` function computes the gradient magnitude using Prewitt or Sobel or Roberts filters, and then thresholds. It is not just computing a derivative. You are just computing a derivative.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes mulSpectrums worked but I got a gray image with white edges. So help me out here, look like I know a lot less than I thought. Normally I would convolve Prewitt kernel with image and I would get a black image with white edges. So what is the black image I posted that I get with convolution, what is this gray image I got with FFT and which one I need? Are they both the derivative of image?

Comment: [This is what a derivative image is supposed to look like](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2016/cmsc426/matlab/filters/html/filters_tutorial_08.png) (that uses Sobel, but Prewitt is not that much different, they both try to approximate the derivative). Where it says "gradient Dx" is it showing the (estimated) derivative along the x-axis. Where it says "gradient Dy" it is showing the derivative along the y-axis. Where it says "Dxy", it is actually showing the gradient magnitude: sqrt(Dx²+Dy²). Each of the derivatives is computed with a single convolution, like what you're trying to do.

Comment: The derivative images are shown with 0 mapped to middle gray, darker pixels have negative values, lighter pixels have positive values. A derivative is a signed function.

Comment: Thanks for everything man, I have only one question left. I element-wise square the results of x-kernel - image FFT and y-kernel - image FFT then I add them. Then I take the square root but output image is still gray. What more should I do? I tried normalizing 0-255 but it is still gray. How do I get the black white image, Dxy in the image you posted?

Comment: This question is extra though, go ahead and post the answer to original question, I'll mark it accepted.